# Need to redirect article to new page Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am new in Drupal world. I want to redirect article from www.sites.com/node/3691 to www.sites.com/events/cpt_award

Both links are on the same site, so I need to make redirection from node path to this new page /events/cpt_award

I have installed Global redirect module but I do not know how to use it. Please help. Drupal version is 7.

Answer (score 0):

Did you update the alias of that node to `events/cpt_award`?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have found what was the problem. I had not set the privilage options for global redirect module, so I did not have option to set url redirection. Now I have fixed it, and it works :)

Comment: OK. Glad to hear that!